# Read and Write on Python

Tags: python

At the moment I'm doing this little excerscie that consist of doing:

1. The input must be interactive from the keyboard. You will take input for 12 students.
2. You will input the students’ name and an average grade. The student cannot enter an
   average below zero or above 100. Your program must raise and handle an exception
   should this occur.
3. Write all output to a file named grades.txt
4. Close the output file.
5. Open the file grades.txt for input.
6. Your program will raise and handle an exception if the file is not found.
7. Read all the records from the file and display them.

I Have this so far but I can't make it work. What can I do?

```
outfile = open('grades.txt', 'w')


def Main():
    print('Please make the Student List: ')
    Input()
     def Input():
#STUDENT INPUT +++++++++++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name1 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName1 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade1 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade1 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade1 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName1) + ',' + str(Name1)+ ': ' + str(Grade1) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
    print()
    Name2 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName2 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade2 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade2 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade2 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName2) + ',' + str(Name2)+ ': ' + str(Grade2) + '\n')   

# +++++++++++++++++++++

    print()
    Name3 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName3 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade3 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade3 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade3 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName3) + ',' + str(Name3)+ ': ' + str(Grade3) + '\n')   

# +++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name4 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName4 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade4 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade4 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade4 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName4) + ',' + str(Name4)+ ': ' + str(Grade4) + '\n')   

# +++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name5 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName5 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade5 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade5 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade5 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName5) + ',' + str(Name5)+ ': ' + str(Grade5) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name6 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName6 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade6 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade6 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade6 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName6) + ',' + str(Name6)+ ': ' + str(Grade6) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++

    print()
    Name7 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName7 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade7 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade7 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade7 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName7) + ',' + str(Name7)+ ': ' + str(Grade7) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++

    print()
    Name8 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName8 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade8 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade8 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade8 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName8) + ',' + str(Name8)+ ': ' + str(Grade8) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++

    print()
    Name9 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName9 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade9 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade9 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade9 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName9) + ',' + str(Name9)+ ': ' + str(Grade9) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name10 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName10 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade10 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade10 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade10 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName10) + ',' + str(Name10)+ ': ' + str(Grade10) + '\n')   

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name11 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName11 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade11 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade11 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade11 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName11) + ',' + str(Name11)+ ': ' + str(Grade11) + '\n')   

# +++++++++++++++++++++
    print()
    Name12 = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LName12 = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
    Grade12 = input("Enter your Grades: ")
    try:
         if Grade12 > 100:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

         elif Grade12 <= 0:
             print ("Oops!  That was not valid answer.")
             Input()

    except:
        outfile.write(str(LName12) + ',' + str(Name12)+ ': ' + str(Grade12) + '\n')   

# +++++++++++++       

    outfile.close()
    Open()
     def Open():
    try:
        infile = open("grades.txt", "w")

    except: print("Error: can't find file or read data")

    line1 = infile.readline()
    line2 = infile.readline()
    line3 = infile.readline()
    line4 = infile.readline()
    line5 = infile.readline()
    line6 = infile.readline()
    line7 = infile.readline()
    line8 = infile.readline()
    line9 = infile.readline()
    line10 = infile.readline()
    line11 = infile.readline()
    line12 = infile.readline()

    infile.close()

    print(line1)
    print(line2)
    print(line3)
    print(line4)
    print(line5)
    print(line6)
    print(line7)
    print(line8)
    print(line9)
    print(line10)
    print(line11)
    print(line12)



Main()
```

Comment: If you have to repeat a lot of code like that, you should think to yourself whether a loop could be utilized.

Comment: `Input()` in `try` block is not assigned to any variabe.

Comment: Input is set to go to Def Input()?

Comment: How do you make Loops with Variables? I could not find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: icktoofay is right. This is worst form of coding approach that a programmer can do.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a structure such as an array or list within a loop to deal with the variables. e.g.

```
names = ["" for x in range(12)]

for i in range(0,len(names) - 1):
   names[i] = input('Enter Name: ')
```

and so on, assigning each variable within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest that you can do:

1) Use a loop to get all the values from the user and store it in an array.

```
 for i in range(12):
     #get details here
```

2) Open a file and write the array contents.

```
 f = open("grades.txt", 'wt')
 #write list contents to file
```

3) Open the same file and display the contents.

```
 f = open("grades.txt", 'rt')
 #display file contents here
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Open()
def Open():
    try:
        infile = open("grades.txt", "r")
    except:
        print("Error: can't find file or read data")
```

When you open file for reading the mode needs to `r`. Or else it will create a new file cleeaning the old data.Also assign `input` in try block to `grade`.

Comment: How could you call `Open()` before it was defined?